# It is a problem for me to tell the difference between grow and grow up. Please enlighten me on it.

Tags: word-choice, phrases

1.To do things you have never done before is called growing.
2.To do things you have never done before is called growing up.

It is a problem for me to tell the difference between grow and grow up. Please enlighten me on it.

Comment: Those aren't real definitions.  Can you include what the dictionary says about *grow* and *grow up*?

Answer (score 0):

The following dictionary definitions seems very similar. My guess is that we have grown to use them each in different ways.

For example, it is typical to call the aging of human beings "growing up" and the aging of plants, "growing."

Another example is that if something is getting larger in size, we say that something is "growing."

Is there a specific sentence you are trying to use one or the other in?

Merriam Webster Definitions:

Grow Up:

- to grow toward or arrive at full stature or physical or mental maturity : to progress from childhood toward adulthood
- to become an adult
- to stop thinking or behaving in a childish way
- to begin to exist and develop as time passes

Grow:

- to spring up and develop to maturity
- to be able to grow in some place or situation
- to increase in size by assimilation of material into the living organism or by accretion of material in a nonbiological process
- to develop from a parent source
- to pass into a condition